# How to bypass SSL when running wget with maven plugin?

Tags: maven, ssl

I want to execute the following wget before mvn starts packaging. But I get the SSL handshake error since the url is HTTPS. Is there a way to bypass this? I tried to add --no-check-cert but it failed.

My objective is to download property files and bundle them into the tar when packaging.

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.maven-download-plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>download-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wget</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <url>https://URL</url>
                        <outputFileName>file.name</outputFileName>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

The file exists on an internal network which my machine have full access to. I have no issues running wget --no-cert on that url.

```
[INFO] --- download-maven-plugin:1.3.0:wget (default) @ project ---
Downloading: https://URL.com/app.properties
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1917)

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.googlecode.maven-download-plugin:download-maven-plugin:1.3.0:wget (default) on project project: IO Error: Could not get content -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: SSL handshake error can have many reasons. But a bad certificate is usually not one of the reasons so bypassing certificate validation will not help. More likely this happens because the local TLS stack is too old compared to what the server expects or the other way around. No command line option will fix such problem. How this can be fixed depends on the exact reason which can usually be only be determined after deeper debugging - but it usually involves either adapting configuration like choice of cipher or upgrading the TLS stack.

Comment: Adding the output of `wget --version` and the URL of the server (in case it is public) might help to narrow down the cause of the handshake error.

Comment: added some more details. im able to wget the file from my machine with no issues.

Comment: This is not the classical handshake error alert I expected. Instead this is a handshake exception thrown from Java - and which is about certificate validation. It looks for me that Maven just uses the `wget` name to signal that it should get data but the actual implementation does not use the wget command line tool but Java instead. Given the error message I expect either a self-signed certificate, missing chain certificates, unknown (company specific) root CA or an SSL intercepting firewall as the reason - but w/o access to the real URL it is hard to tell.

Comment: yeah self sign cert, the url is internal i cant give that. i guess i can force jenkins to do it instead of maven. i figured id do it here since i can easily edit without having to go to jenkins

Comment: Upd:In the article above there is a very clear solution for such cases: the remote repository, you are trying to download with maven wget plugin, is using https protocol. If anyone still need the answeer is here:
http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-repository-ssl.html